# Convert raster format from 1 format to another

Tags: gis, tiff, gdal, geo

I have some .TIFF files that I would like to turn into a geotiff. I've been told to look at GDAL but Im not really sure where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're okay using the command line, GDAL is a great tool, especially when paired with technologies like PostGIS (a geospatial database if you're not sure), but that's a whole different matter. If not, I suggest trying out a piece of software called FME, which has quite a friendly GUI for converting datatypes, including that of TIFF files into GEOTIFFs.

https://www.safe.com/convert/tiff/geotiff/

If you do want to try with GDAL, the **gdal_translate** is the command you're looking for. You'll need to do a fair bit of setup/config work before you get to that stage but below is an example of how simple the conversion or 'translation' command is:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "TILED=YES" utm.tif utm_tiled.tif
```

Although I was pretty broad, hope this helped!

Comment: gdal_translate is exactly what I was after! :) thanks

Comment: The link to safe.com is broken.

Comment: @swatchai I had a rogue ] at the end! Fixed